# Delphi: Send message to running instance of same app, without any TForm

Tags: delphi, sendmessage

I'd like to know a way to do the following:

App starts, no forms created.
2nd App instance starts, it detects one instance is already running (this is sorted already)

I want 2nd instance to send the 1st one a message, without using BROADCAST; Id like a way to find a handle to the 1st instance to send it the message directly.

The 1st instance must have a class name to be found with that the 2nd one hasn't yet created, so that it won't send the message to itself.

How would I use FindWindow in this scenario? How do I create a window-less class/object identifiable by FindWindow?

Comment: `FindWindow` finds a **window** by either class name or caption, so it can't *find* anything that is windowless. (That's why the function is called `Find**Window**)`. It also returns a **window** handle - if it *could* find something that was **windowless**, what would it return?

Comment: Well I can create a "window" with AllocateHWnd, but then I don't know how to find it from the other instance.

Comment: Well, if you create a **window** with `AllocateHWnd`, it's not **windowless**, is it? And you specifically asked about using `FindWindow` to find a **windowless** application. "How di I create a window-less class/object identifiable by FindWindow?" were your **exact** words.

Comment: @KenWhite "windowless" in this context means no TForm instance, it is wrong, because not only TForm is a window. So every "windowless" should be replaced by "formless". There is no need of kicking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send messages to the `TApplication` window if you know the value of its `Title` property. The sending instance can temporarily set its own `Title` to a different value so as not to confuse `FindWindow()`. The receiving instance can use the `TApplication.OnMessage` event or `TApplication.HookMainWindow()` method to receive the message.

Answer (score 2):

You can not find windowless object by means of FindWindow.

But you can create invisible window with **AllocateHWnd** function - see TTimer source as   example. Use SetWindowText to set title for easy searching

Comment: If you create a windows using `AllocateHWnd`, then it's no longer windowless, and the question asked for **windowless** specifically.

Comment: Some people consider programs without visible windows as windowless, I think

Answer (score 1):

You could use shared memory to pass data. [See this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details

Comment: Don't used shared memory. Send messages.

Comment: Using that already for other purposes, but in this case I wanna sort the issue with SendMessage